# How to store the name of user logged in?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

I want to store the name of the user who is currently logged into Django in a custom form.  In the admin we can do so by writing modified_by=request.user.username, but how do I do this in my own form?

Comment: This is a very frequently asked question. Did you try and search before posting?

Comment: @Daniel I thought the same, but I've done a couple searches and can't actually find a duplicate on SO.  Maybe I'm using the wrong search terms.  If you find a duplicate I'll vote to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either define the __init__ method of your Form to accept a "request" parameter, and then pass that in from your view, or you can use the [thread-locals](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CookBookThreadlocalsAndUser) hack.

Comment: hello please provide a satisfactory answer

Comment: this is an *satisfactory answer*

Comment: @ha22109 If you want more details, you could explain what you've tried, what isn't working, where you're having trouble, etc. If you put in a minimum of effort, I'm glad to help out.