# How to log the username who is currently loged in form.py?

Tags: django, django-forms

How to log the username who is currently loged in form.py?

Comment: Duplicate of ha22109's question asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939157/how-to-store-the-name-of-user-logged-in

Comment: Jarret, you didn't notice yet another strange thing. This question is by "ha22109" too. And in that last question too, he was talked for repeating already submitted question.

Comment: harshh... actually, I did notice that :-) As near as I can tell, ha22109 was looking for a verbatim code example, which Van Gale has now provided, so hopefully a) the example is sufficiently copy/paste ready, and b) this round will finally help.

Comment: besides giving comment try giving solution dear

Answer (score 5):

You need an `__init__` method on your form, and pass request.user as an argument.

For example:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    # Notice the custom argument 'user'
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # do something here with user, such as calling log.debug()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

Now in your views.py, you create the form like this:

```
form = MyModelForm(request.user)
```

or, if you are processing POST request:

```
form = MyModelForm(request.user, request.POST)
```

---

**Edit** to update answer after comment.

To get the user in the admin site you need to add the following method to your admin model in admin.py:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    # Do something with request.user here
    obj.save()
```

Of course, this means you only have access to the user during a save.  If you need access to request.user for other parts of admin, such as filtering querysets, see this post by James Bennett for more info:

[Users and the admin](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/dec/24/admin/)

Comment: I m not making a view for this .Can i do so in my admin.py
'form =MyModelForm(reuest.user)
i only have form.py and admin.py

Answer (score -1):

{{ request.user }}

Comment: that won't help forms processing.

Comment: You could very well store it in a hidden form field.

I agree Van Gale's approach is djangoic and elegant. But one simple solution definitely is to store a hidden form element containing userid.